# Android - URL not accessing in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with the `WebView` implemented in my application, having the web links must be open in the app browser.

I am using the following code for `Webview` layout:

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webadd"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

and the java code:

```
String url="http://www.google.co.in"
webadd=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webadd);
webadd.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) ;
webadd.loadUrl(url);
```

Here the problem is that

#### the URL is getting loaded in the Phone default browser skipping the app browser instead of getting loaded into app browser.

How to resolve this problem with the links/ sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You means that you want to load the same URL in WebView residing within the Application,  if this is the case then create a class by extending **`WebViewClient`**.

```
String url="http://www.google.co.in"
webadd=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webadd);
webadd.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webadd.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());  
webadd.loadUrl(url); 

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient  
        {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);  
            }  

            @Override  
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

                view.loadUrl(url);  
                return true;  

            }  
        }
```

Comment: +1, but i got the solution before u answered. Anyway, thanks for the solution. please tell the reason why its getting loaded into the default browser? Please define webview client?

Comment: @avadhani check the ["Handling Page Navigation"](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)